# How to create a function for getting a largest polygon from 2 polygons using case statement in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, polygon, area, function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.largest_polygon1(
  geom1 geometry,
  geom2 geometry)
  RETURNS geometry
  LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

  COST 100
  VOLATILE
   AS $BODY$
  begin
   Return
    Case 
       When ST_Area(geom1) > ST_Area(geom2) Then geom1
     else geom2
    End;
  End;
 $BODY$;

  ALTER FUNCTION public.largest_polygon1(geometry, geometry)
 OWNER TO postgres;
```

Comment: what is not working?

Comment: In this code, I need to find the largest polygon of two polygons geom1 and geom2 using case statement, do you have any idea to correct this?

Comment: what happens when you run this function? what is not working?

Comment: 'ERROR: FEHLER: Anfrage hat keinen Bestimmungsort für die Ergebnisdaten HINT: Wenn Sie die Ergebnisse eines SELECT verwerfen wollen, verwenden Sie stattdessen PERFORM. CONTEXT: PL/pgSQL-Funktion largest_polygon1(geometry,geometry) Zeile 3 bei SQL-Anweisung SQL state: 42601' This is the error I got.

Comment: `begin
return
 Case 
 When ST_Area(geom1) > ST_Area(geom2) Then geom1
  else geom2
 End;
End;` Then after using this I got the answer now.

Comment: please use the edit button to update your question, this will prompt the system to consider reopening your question

Comment: You seem to have answered the question in the Question; once reopened, the Question should be a question, and you can then add an Answer.

Comment: At first I don't know the answer then I found and I don't know where I have to answer. That's why I edited there itself.